"Super" (aka "windows") key not working in Dell Ubuntu 22.04
just got a Dell Precision 5940 laptop shipped with Ubuntu 22.04.
The "super" (aka "windows") key is not working.. I use it a lot for example for moving windows on a right or left side of the screen (using SUPER+arrow keys).
Even more "strange" if I enable multiple keyboards and check the layouts I can see that the super keyboard got actually catched when I press it, but somehting in the middle is blocking from working as expected :-///
If I run xev I got:
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xe00001,
    root 0x7ba, subw 0x0, time 873582, (165,-21), root:(285,93),
    state 0x2000, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False



If your left windows Super is not working correctly install Tweaks (if not already installed) from Ubuntu Software and navigate your way to Keyboard & Mouse.

check which key is set under Keyboard for Overview Shortcut and set it to Left Super or as desired.

your comment makes no sense. Bottom left corner of the Dock is a 9 dot grid Show Applications Click on that and in the search box type ubuntu then select the large yellow icon Ubuntu Software to run it...
